# Rename an img tag and make it self-closing

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to change the img tag with amp-img tag without removing the img tag attributes and its value.

Here is my code:

```
var content = '<div><img src="abcd" height="200" width="210"><img src="bcda" width="50" height="25"></div>';
        let replace1 = content.replace(/<img/g, '<amp-img'); //So far so good here
        let replace2 = replace1.replace(/>/g, '/>'); // Here I would like to append a close for amp-img only, not for all tag
        console.log(replace2)
```

How can I append close tag for amp-img only?

Answer (score 3):

You can use: `<img([^>]+)>` and this `<amp-img$1/>` for replacement.

```js
var content = '<div><img src="abcd" height="200" width="210"><img src="bcda" width="50" height="25"></div>';
let replace1 = content.replace(/<img([^>]+)>/g, '<amp-img$1/>'); 
console.log(replace1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, sir . Could you please explain to me what the dollar sign and its number mean ?

Comment: `$1` Means first captured group, in regex anything between parentheses is a group. in this particular regex first group (and only) will capture img attributes.

Comment: Okay I got it now. I ticked up your answer already, sir. 